# Отправка запроса и получение ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Нужно отправить запрос через API для расчета стоимости доставки, не могу понять в чем ошибка.

[Вот ссылка на API](https://api.exline.systems/docs/public).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function goQuery(){
var places= new Array;

    /*ajax */  $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         url: "https://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin",
         datatype:'json',
          data: {
              title:$('#otcuda').val()
          },

   /* success */  success: function(data){
               alert('Load was performed.'+);
               console.log(result);
             var pl_count = 0;
       /* each data*/     
               $.each( data.regions,function(){
                var pl_id=$(this).find("id").text();
                var pl_name=$(this).find("title").text();
                var cashed_path=$(this).find("cached_path").text();

                 var result = {

                     id: pl_id,
                     title: pl_name,
                     cached_path : cashed_path
                 };
                 pl_count++;
        /* each data*/     });

      /* success */    },
  // error: alert('error')

   /*ajax */   });
console.log(regions.valueOf(pl));
});
</script>
```

Comment: @PloadyFree формулировка очень точная )

Comment: @NickVolynkin энивэй так будет красивее)

Answer (score 1):

Проверь что тебе возвращает `$('#otcuda').val()` через консоль разработчика в отладке.

Следующий код работает корректно:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "https://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
        title: 'Аст'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```